# Libavg - change id of connected node

Tags: libavg

I just can't figure it out.

What I want to do is changing the id of a node, but this node is connected, so I cannot change the id.

What's the best way to somehow disconnect the node and then change the id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The id of a node is read-only and can't be changed.